# Monadic Records Containing Polymorphic Functions

Tags: haskell, monads

So, say that I define the data types

```
data WAtom a = WAtom {innerVal :: a, temper :: WPart a -> WPart a }

data WPart a where 
     WUnit :: WAtom a -> WPart a
     WCompound :: WAtom a -> WAtom a -> WPart a

atomize :: WPart a -> a
atomize (WUnit a) = innerVal a
{- Write one for compound too -}
```

Now I want to make WPart an instance of Monad. All seems well so far.
I'd like `bind` to operate by calling the bound function on the innerVal of the monad to produce a new monad. Then call this new monad's `temper` on the original monad:

```
instance Monad (WPart) where
     return a = WUnit $ WAtom a
     (WUnit c) >>= f = let new_part = f $ innerVal c in
                           (temper $ atomize new_part) (WUnit c)
```

However, this doesn't typecheck. The definition of monad maintains that the `f` in bind can change the inner type of the monad. This makes sense to me. However, I seem to be on the horns of a dilemma: 1) If I constrain what type WAtom can take, say define the data type instead as `WAtom Int` then I will run afoul of the Kind restriction on Monads * -> *. But if I don't, then I cannot know that the `f` in bind will return a monad of the same type as the original monad passed in. Furthermore, I can't make `temper` existentially quantified for obvious reasons.

I'm sure I'm just thinking about this wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Best,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `WUnit c :: WPart a` we have `f :: a -> WPart b` so `new_part :: WPart b` and `atomize new_part :: b`... so we already can't call `temper :: forall a. WAtom a -> WPart a -> WPart a` unless we could constrain `b ~ WPart (WAtom e)` for some `e`. Worse yet, even if `temper $ atomize new_part :: WPart b -> WPart b` we still have `WUnit c :: WPart a` where `a ~ b` does not, in general, hold.

So, that's definitely not an implementation of `Monad`.